# How to create custom options with related dependencies on Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento, dependencies, magento-1.9

Use **Magento 1.9** + **Mageworx Custom Options**

I'm generating **custom options** for various magento products from php code.
Everything works but **dependencies** can not figure out how to generate them.

I know that there is a column called 'dependent_id' on the table 'catalog_product_option_type_value' on the database, and there are probably some methods in the Mageworx classes. But I would like to look for a faster solution instead of writing an ad hoc function to manage these ids.

However I would like to solve the problem using the function

```
// get $options (from POST request)
// get $product (from ID usually)
$product -> setProductOptions ( $options )
```

The `$options` come from an ajax call with json parameters, the words 'dependent', 'child', 'children', 'depends' have been tried. But nothing the function does not seem to convert values into dependencies.

Does anyone have any ideas or have ever tried to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get somewhat of this kind:

```
options[xx]['is_depended'] = 0 (no) 1 (or) 2 (and)
options[xx]['values'][yy]['depended_ids'] = option_value_id
```

this (or similar) way:

```
foreach ($productOptions as $option) {
 $option->setIsDepended(0/1/2)
 foreach ($option->getValues() as $optionValue) {
     $optionValue->setDependentIds('5,6,7,8');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution to fix the mentioned issue.

```
foreach ($productOptions as $option) {
 $option->setIsDepended(0/1/2)
 foreach ($option->getValues() as $optionValue) {
     $optionValue->setDependentIds('5,6,7,8');
 }
}
```